# Convert Date to Text without losing the format in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, cell-formatting

I have a column in Excel Sheet which contains all the dates in custom `dd-mm-yyyy` format. I need to convert all these dates to text without losing the format. If I am changing the cell format to Text, I am losing the format. I tried to copy the cell values as values but did not work. I searched a lot on the internet, but did not find any useful resource. What's the possible solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `TEXT` function.

```
=TEXT(A1,"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula for keeping the long date format from "A1" cell in another cell (exp: "B1"):

**=TEXT(A1,"[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")**

The cell "A1" is a cell contains a date (such as today date with «today()» formula) with long date format.

Also, you can use this VBA code for getting same format with specify *font* and *size* in print's header:
**ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&""Arial Rounded MT Bold,Regular""&16" & Range("B1").Value**

This code will shows the "B1" cell (as a text from "A1" cell) in Right of Header in Print.